# IEEE EDAS final Paper upload error: line space and font size

Tags: ieeetran, overleaf, ieee-style, ieeeconf

I am trying to upload my final manuscript on EDAS system. I am using the standard IEEE Conference latex template with 10pt font size. I have used \begin{table*} command to include a table spanning over two columns.

EDAS is showing an upload error: Upload failed: The paper has an average line spacing of 9 pt, but should have 12. You may need to increase your font size.

How can I resolve this issue?
Need urgent help as the deadline is approaching.

A similar question asked before, but there is no solution yet:
[latex dynamic font size IEEE conference format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/544707/latex-dynamic-font-size-ieee-conference-format)
[Upload IEEEtran paper fail towards EDAS checking process](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/552569/upload-ieeetran-paper-fail-towards-edas-checking-process)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am facing the same issue, currently I boiled it down to the references causing this issue. EDAS seems to include for some reason also the reference section when computing the average line spacing. However, I am using the standard IEEETran bib style.

**UPDATE**

After creating many minimum working examples which work in EDAS, I figured out that figures were causing this issue. So I converted all figures from double column to single column, remove the subcaption package, rearranged the figures.

**UPDATE 2**

Avoid multi-line figure captions.

Answer (score 1):

We're having the same issue (for some papers) and it really seems like EDAS is in some cases incorrectly calculating the average line spacing. You could contact your conference publication chairs (perhaps this issue is from some EDAS parameter configuration).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue as well and this ultimately ended up being an issue with the EDAS system itself. Since I pointed this issue out to them, they created a FAQ answer and now rely on the chairs of the conference to set the line spacing to be more forgiving to fit with their system.

Below is the FAQ:

https://edas.info/showFAQ.php?q=1145

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I solved this by

\usepackage[singlespacing]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.0041841} % 12 pt/11.95pt

you just need to divide the standard value 12 pt by the mentioned value e.g 11.95 in my case the result value put it in the setstretch command.

Comment: you saved my life!

Answer (score 0):

I was using \subfigure for my figures. I changed it to spread over a single column using \begin{figure*}. This trick worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and the following worked for me

I declared the font size as 10 while declaring the iEEEtran document class, like this

`\documentclass[conference,10pt]{IEEEtran}`

Then the line spacing issue was gone but another issue came for the bottom margin. I removed the page numbers from the paper using the following command

`\pagenumbering{gobble}`

which solved the bottom margin issue but now the font embedding issue came, which I solved by creating a pdf of my paper using an online tool (https://online2pdf.com). Here you can upload your pdf created by Latex and convert it to create another pdf with the font embedding issue solved.

After this, I uploaded my file and I was successful :)

Comment: Hi and welcome. Your answer seems legit but might be difficult to understand for beginners. If time permits, may you come back and expand your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem of line spacing by adding the following

```
\usepackage[singlespacing]{setspace} 
\setstretch{1.01352}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar situation last week when submitting a conference paper using EDAS. However, the above-mentioned solutions did not resolve the error, despite me even using MS Word method template, from the conference organizers >_<

I eventually resolved this problem by increasing individual section's content fontsize from 10pt to 10.5pts. Thereafter, submission became a breeze. I hope

PS: For some reason, EDAS did not consider the size of the references

Comment: Whic command did you use?